# What is the name of the settings action button icon on android?

Tags: android, icons, drawable

I am trying to create an action button that linked to a settings activity. But I don't know what is the name of the settings action button icon (looks like a gear with six teeth) in @android:drawable.

Comment: The gear icon is the old one. Better to use the icon with the 3 vertical dots

Answer (score 7):

I have attached the URL. https://design.google.com/icons/
Search for settings and then you will see the same icon what you are looking for.
You would be able to download the icon and it will be saved as ic_settings_black_24dp.png format. Attach the same file to your draw able file. 
@android:drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp

Comment: The link is not working. Probably you are referring to https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons:home or https://design.google/resources/

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin in your Android studio. This plugin has all the materialized standard Android icons
 https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin